# BottomNavigationView in layout with ListView init

Tags: android, xml, listview

I have an activity that has two layout XML files.
**activity_main.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f1f3fa">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_contact"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and **content_main.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_linear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_linear"
            android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/search_start_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_box"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/search_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp">

                </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Without **ListView** When I clicked on **SearchView**, keyboards open correctly. But with **ListView** when keyboard open, **BottomNavigationView** goes up.

How can I solve that problem to avoid **BottomNavigationView** goes up?

Comment: Make your content_main.xml a child of ScrollView. Instead of a relative layout. Since scrollview can have only one direct child, just put all of your existing xml code inside scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add the following to your AndroidMainfest.xml :

```
   <activity
android:name="com.companyname.applicationname"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Make your content_main.xml a child of ScrollView. Instead of a relative layout. Since scrollview can have only one direct child, just put all of your existing xml code inside scrollview.

content_main.xml

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_linear"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_start_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_box"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="some text"
                android:textColor="#333"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/search_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

            </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: SearchView goes behind of toolbar. so I add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to ScrollView. Now I tested again and the problem has remained.

Comment: try setting the height of bottomnavigationview to 0dp.

Comment: Now I have not any Bottomnavigationview on screen.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not understanding your issue properly. Okay, so do two things, first in your AndroidMainfest.xml file add this line <activity
    android:name="com.companyname.applicationname"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> and then in your scrollview add this line android:isScrollContainer="false" and also change the scrollview height and width to fill_parent. Wait, I'll edit the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It is working correctly. But when I want to use this layout for a fragment, in another activity that has drawerlayout it does not work correctly.

Comment: The above mentioned code snippet is for activities, for use in fragment, you'll have to set the framelayout container in your other activity's xml height's to 0dp and also the height of bottom navigation view to 0dp as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I set FramLayout's height and bottomnavigationview's height 0 but it is not ok.

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: You can see my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567062/bottomnavigationview-and-listview-in-a-framelyout)