# BottomNavigationView and ListView in a FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

My **MainActivity** is a **Navigation Drawer Activity** that has a **FrameLayout** init and three fragments are attached to this activity.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myapp.app.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.myapp.app.MainActivity">

</FrameLayout>
```

and my fragment layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/content_search"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and **content_Seacrh** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/main_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_box">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_start_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_box"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/search_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_pagination_linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_before"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:background="@color/transparent" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I want to each time that **SearchView** clicked, **BottomNavigationView** hide but Now it does not work and **BottomNavigationView** goes up with the keyboard. If I removed **ListView** from layout it works correctly and **BottomNavigationView** hide when keyboard goes up.

I wrote this line in my **Manifest.xml**:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's the same thing as before. Make your content_search a child of scrollview.

Comment: I try that but not solved my problem.

Comment: And along with it did you try to make frame container's height as 0dp??

Comment: I set the height of FrameLayout 0 but it just hides all things!

Comment: I use this search_content.xml in another activity and it is ok but in this fragment, in MainActivity it has the problem.